# Single channel or even compression with getUserMedia

Tags: compression, audio-recording, getusermedia

Is there some way to just get the left channel (not even sure if both channels do automatically get written to, even though microphone is mono) and, ideally, to compress the data from that channel. The only option I've seen written about is navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}. Is that really it?

Comment: Have a look at [web audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Comment: I presume this is an entirely different and unrelated thing to getUserMedia?

Comment: Not at all. getUserMedia produces a MediaStream, which can be an input (sourceNode) in web audio, using `new AudioContext().createMediaStreamSource(await getUserMedia({audio: true}));`

Comment: aha cool thanks, I'll try to work with that.